# jQuery - Hover not working

Tags: jquery, html

Having a little trouble with `.hover()`

I'm grabbing some dribbble shots, which are pulled in on page load. And for some reason adding a class via hover doesn't want to work on them.

Although it works perfectly fine with a standard list.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HX2NM/1/)

**JS:**

```
$("#dribbble li").hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dribbble">
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you expect to see? Where is your CSS?

Comment: Your hover events is workin pretty well. It is not visible due to the jribbble plugin. Perhaps because they ar using some kind of e.stopPropagation() code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use delegation - I'm guessing your elements aren't getting bound because it's they aren't available in the dom at the time of binding

```
$("#dribbble").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
       $(this).addClass("hover");
    },
    mouseleave:function () {
       $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
},'li');
```

Also you'll have to be more specific with your css if you want it to take precedence over the other styles

```
#dribbble li.hover {
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8hyjD/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to attach event handlers to elements that exist already. As you are creating li elements you must bind to a parent and then filter to the element you require (which is actually desirable when done correctly).

Try:

```
$("#dribbble").on('mouseenter','li',function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});

$("#dribbble").on('mouseleave','li',function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```